# Parsing nested JSON from cloud in dart but getting type error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to to parse JSON from cloud, the data was received,
I tried so many solution here in stackOverflow but the haven't work to me, I'm just string to get familiar with flutter and dart.

but i got this error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Category>'
```

here it is my code:
JSON data I received:
{
"totalRowCount": 1,
"pageSize": 100,
"categories": [{
"CategoryName": "Beverages",
"CategoryID": 1
}]
}

Services.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'Category.dart';

class Services {
  static const String url = 'http://example.com/category';

  static Future<List<Category>> getCategories() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      final category = categoryFromJson(response.body);
      return category;
    } else{
      return List<Category>();
    }
  }
}
```

Category.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
List<Category> categoryFromJson(String str) => List<Category>.from(json.decode(str));

class Category {
  Category({
    this.totalRowCount,
    this.pageSize,
    this.categories,
  });

  final int totalRowCount;
  final int pageSize;
  final List<CategoryElement> categories;

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Category(
      totalRowCount: json["totalRowCount"],
      pageSize: json["pageSize"],
      categories: List<CategoryElement>.from(json["categories"]),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "totalRowCount": totalRowCount,
    "pageSize": pageSize,
    "categories": List<dynamic>.from(categories.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class CategoryElement {
  CategoryElement({
    this.categoryName,
    this.categoryId,
  });

  final String categoryName;
  final int categoryId;

  factory CategoryElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CategoryElement(
    categoryName: json["CategoryName"],
    categoryId: json["CategoryID"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "CategoryName": categoryName,
    "CategoryID": categoryId,
  };
}
```

any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `jsonDecode` on `response.body` to convert the response to a `Map`.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final category = Category.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

Remove the following line, it's causing the issue. Decode it right away using the factory instead of creating another function. That function is invalid because `List.from` accepts an iterable and you're supplying a `Map`. Also, the json response is not a `List`.

```dart
List<Category> categoryFromJson(String str) => List<Category>.from(json.decode(str));
```

Comment: Ah `category.dart` is messed up.